# Database-Based & Redis-Based Customer-Session Empty Data Issue in Magento 2 Using 2 Web-Servers

Tags: magento-2.1, database, ajax, customer-session, redis

I am facing a problem in getting session data in **Magento 2**, when I deploy my Build on **2 Web-Servers**. I am facing no issue on **Single Web-Server**.

> **Problem Details** I am setting some data in session, in first AJAX request, and then getting that data in the next consecutive AJAX
>   request but the session returns no values.

AJAX-Request Format:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: myData,
    cache: false,
})
```

**Problem Resolution Approaches**

- Printed overall session data and found empty customer data. Only the following data is returned.

  `Array([customer_segment_ids] => Array([1] => Array([0] => 3))[wishlist_item_count] => 0)`
- Tried to load session data using **ObjectManager**, while created object of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` and provided the **SessionID** to get data from the Database-Table using my custom code, but it returned *empty array*.
- Tried to load session data using **MySQL Custom Query** by **SessionID** on that table and got data.
- Changed Session storage to **Redis** in my `app/etc/env.php` file, as directed [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html), but got the same empty session issue.
- Changed Session storage to **Files** in my `app/etc/env.php` file and I got the correct data as expected.

  ---

Can I have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to get customer data with the cache enabled which I can achieve by the following code. But you are using the ajax controller request so for you cache will be no problem. kindly share your full code here.

```
namespace QaisarSatti\Module\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $objectmanager;  


  public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager

    ) {


        $this->objectmanager = $objectmanager;

    }
    public function getCustomerData()
    {
         $customerSession = $this->objectmanager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();
         return $customerSession;
    }

}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/knowledge-base/get-customer-session-data-with-cache-in-block/)

Comment: Thank you for your consideration,
There is nothing special about my code, I used the conventional way to get data from the **Customer-Session**, as follows;

`namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Area;`

`use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;`

`class MyController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`
`{`

 `protected $_customerCollection;`
 
 `public function __construct(Session $customerSession)`
 `{`
  `$this->_customerSession = $customerSession;`
 `}`

 `public function execute()`
 `{`
  `$myData = $this->_customerSession->getMyCustomData();`
 `}`

`}`

Comment: @JehangirWahid if you want to get customer attribute then load through the model. follow
https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento2-load-customer-by-id/

Comment: No Sir, I am not trying to get **Customer Attributes**. I am setting some **custom data** in session the first client request, and then am trying to get that data in the next consecutive request.

Comment: Can you share code where you set the session?

Comment: Yes, for sure.
`namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Controller\Area; use Magento\Customer\Model\Session; class MyController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action { protected $_customerCollection; public function __construct(Session $customerSession) { $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; } public function execute() { // $myData is an array $this->_customerSession->setMyCustomData($myData); } }`

Comment: **I am terribly sorry to mention that I have 2 Web Servers. Let me edit my Question.**